# How to create android widget using react native?

Tags: android, react-native, widget

Is it possible to make android widget using react-native?
I have done some search to find an approach but only find  [this repo](https://github.com/netbeast/react-native-android-widget-poc)

Is it any other approach to make android widget using react-native?

Comment: Aso there is this: https://github.com/surialabs/react-native-widget-example

Answer (score 0):

Currently this feature is not available.

[vote to be implemented.](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/android-home-screen-widget)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by using the bridge for more details : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios