# Use React Native to create UI of android widget

Tags: android, react-native, widget

I know  [currently](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/android-home-screen-widget)  there is not any  [straight forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087282/how-to-create-android-widget-using-react-native)  approach to create android widget using react native, But I have created a native android widget (using android studio), How can I add react native elements to its UI?

Comment: Any updates on this? Would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library "react-native-android-widget-poc" to create and use android widgets easily in react-native.